# Syntax error when adding foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints, database-schema, ddl

I am trying to set a `DEFAULT` value and `NOT NULL` for `type_id` column which is a foreign key to `instance` table but it is complaining about MySQL syntax.

```
CREATE TABLE `type` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city` varchar(256)
); 

ALTER TABLE instance ADD COLUMN type_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE instance ADD CONSTRAINT instance_xbf1 DEFAULT 1
FOREIGN KEY (type_id)
REFERENCES type(id) int(10) unsigned NOT NULL;
```

It is complaining about the syntax of the last statement:

> Error: \"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT 1\nFOREIGN KEY (type_id)\nREFERENCES type(id) int(10) unsi' at line 1\")", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: `it is complaining about mysql syntax` Those _complaints_ contain very specific messages that tell you exactly what the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do too many things in your `ADD CONSTRAINT` statement for the foreign key.

You can add the default value in two ways. Either as part of the column definition:

```
ALTER TABLE instance ADD COLUMN type_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1;
```

Or later in it's own statement:

```
ALTER TABLE instance ALTER type_id SET DEFAULT 1;
```

In the foreign key you cannot define the properties of the column such as data type, nullability, default values etc...

The error message is telling you it's not expecting the `DEFAULT` keyword as part of an `ADD CONSTRAINT`. If you remove that, it will then complain about the data type & nullability part: `int(10) unsigned NOT NULL` because it's not expecting those either. But you have already defined them anyway.

So, your `ADD CONSTRAINT` can be simplified to:

```
ALTER TABLE instance ADD CONSTRAINT instance_xbf1
FOREIGN KEY (type_id) REFERENCES type(id);
```